# Calling void function from other script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to call some code from my PlayerManager script into my PlayerController script.
This is the code in the PlayerManger script:

```
public void Died()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Destroy(controller);
        CreateController();
    }
```

And this is the code in my Playercontroller script:

```
void Die()
    {
        PlayerManager.Died();
    }
```

When I try to run my code, I get the error: "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'PlayerManager.Died()'" Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code, or what I have to do to fix it.

Comment: Make it **Static**

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change code like this

You cannot execute non-static method

```
public static void Died()
    {
        PhotonNetwork.Destroy(controller);
        CreateController();
    }
```